# While closing and reopen modal extra click event trigger again when I do single click on toggle button open modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a modal that open and close properly but when I re-open the modal and do click on the toggle button extra click event fire(means total two click event on a single click).

```js
 //open modal close modal
    $("#my-id").modal('show', {
        backdrop: 'static'
    });
    $("#my-id").modal('hide');

   
    

    //javascript
    $('#togle').change(function() {
      if ($(this).prop('checked') == true) {
                $(this).val("1");
                    console.log('1')
      } else {
                $(this).val("0");
                    console.log('0')
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<input id="togle" type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle"  >
```

Comment: Please share your code.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to contain the modal, and everything seems to work as I would expect. Can you make sure the code in your question reproduces the issue?

Comment: Where is your modal?